# How to change a binary variable dependent upon another binary variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using a larger version of the following dataset:

```
Name  HB>TE-iL   TE-iL   TE-iL^
John    1          1        0
Eric    0          0        0
Mike    1          1        0
Jim     0          1        0
Joe     1          0        1
...
```

If column `HB>TE-iL` for a given observation is equal to one, I want the `TE-iL` and `TE-iL^` columns to become zeros. So the above data frame would become:

```
Name  HB>TE-iL   TE-iL  TE-iL^
John    1          0        0
Eric    0          0        0
Mike    1          0        0
Jim     0          1        0
Joe     1          0        0   
...
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Detect where it is 1
is_1 = your_data[["HB>TE-iL"]] == 1
# set to 0
your_data[is_1, c("TE-iL", "TE-iL^")] = 0
```

Comment: what is the [[ ]] (double brackets) about   / how do you read that    i would have thought about it like this 

df$'TE-iL^'[df$'TE-iL^' == 1] <- 0

with single brackets

Comment: That would work too. Double brackets is the same as `$`, except that it takes strings as inputs and can work with variables.. Your column names are weird so they would need backticks, and I prefer `df[["HB>TE-iL"]]` to `df$\`HB>TE-iL\``. Quotes with `$` are unusual and look strange to me, so I avoid them.

Comment: You could also do, e.g., `my_col = "HB>TE-iL"` and `df[[my_col]]` will still work, but `df$my_col` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
df[c("TE-iL", "TE-iL^")] <- df[c("TE-iL", "TE-iL^")] * !df[["HB>TE-iL"]]
```

-output

```
df
#  Name HB>TE-iL TE-iL TE-iL^
#1 John        1     0      0
#2 Eric        0     0      0
#3 Mike        1     0      0
#4  Jim        0     1      0
#5  Joe        1     0      0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("John", "Eric", "Mike", "Jim", "Joe"), 
    `HB>TE-iL` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), `TE-iL` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L), `TE-iL^` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: This updates *all* values of those two columns, not just the values of the matching rows. For instance, there's no guidance that anything should be changed when `"HB>TE-iL"` is 0, but this code will force that update.

Comment: @r2evans I used `!df[["HB>TE-iL"]]`

Comment: @r2evans it's okay.  Thank you sir for the comments

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(
     `TE-iL` = case_when(`HB>TE-iL` == 1 ~ 0),
     `TE-iL^` = case_when(`HB>TE-iL` == 1 ~ 0)
   )
```

Comment: You'll need backticks around all the column names as they are non-standard

Comment: good point

rogues77 like this maybe

mutate(df$'TE-iL^' =

Comment: With this code, all non-matching rows have those columns set to `NA`. Two thoughts: (1) add a default, as in `TRUE ~ \`TE-iL\``; and (2) since it's simple, it might be shorter to use `if_else(\`HB>TE-iL\` == 1, 0, \`TB-iL\`)` (and similar for the other).